# Fragment's id and tag are not set when using navigation component

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have the problem that my **fragment's id and tag** are not set although I specify them in my `mobile_navigation.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/nav_frag1">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_frag1"
        android:tag="abcdef"
        android:name="org.example.myproject.MyFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_frag1"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_frag1" />

    ...

</navigation>
```

When I try to access the id and tag programmatically in my fragment via `this.getId()` or `this.getTag()` the id is always the same **very high integer** for all fragments (a little smaller than max int) and the tag is **null**.

The navigation is put together in my main activity. The code is basically the **example drawer navigation project** created by Android Studio. I did not change anything about it.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.frag1, R.id.frag2, R.id.frag3)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }

}
```

Am I missing something about the way the id and tag has to be set?

Edit: An **example project** that demonstrates the unexpected behavior can be found at https://github.com/flauschtrud/FragmentTagAndIdTest.

Comment: Hello, where did you call `this.getTag()` ?

Comment: In the ```onCreateView()``` method of the fragment.

Comment: It will return null in `onCreateView()` as still the fragment view is not created yet by associating it its layout... please call it in `onViewCreated` instead

Comment: I just put the code into ```onViewCreated()``` but the values are still not set. And the same with ```onResume()```.

Comment: What is the use of `MainActivity` code? It's better to provide fragment code

Comment: I added the code for ```MainActivity``` since I suspect that the issue might be related to the way the navigation is set up. The Fragment code is not really interesting. I updated my question with a link to an example project that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The **fragment tag** into a **navigation tag** it is a destination([Anatomy of a destination here](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started#anatomy)), so you can define: id, name, label.

```
<navigation>
    <fragment></fragment>
</navigation>
```

Unlike **fragment tag** into a **xml layout**, where the implementation get the **android:tag attr** and uses it when inflates the Fragment from **android:name**.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

   <fragment
      android:id="@+id/someFragment"
      android:tag="someTagNameToSomeFragment"
      android:name="com.somepackagename.SomeFragment"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The same happens about the **android:id**, its the id resource for that destination, not the **Fragment id**. We have two ways to set an id for a Fragment, either from xml layout file (like example above) or through a transaction. From a transaction (commit kotlin extension from an Activity):

```
supportFragmentManager.commit { add(R.id.someFragment, SomeFragment()) }
```

I'm assuming that **R.id.nav_host_fragment** is the id that you give to NavHostFragment container (View) defined on xml layout. In this situation, each time you navigates to a new **destination** the before Fragment View is destroyed and the new Fragment and its View is created. The Fragment id on those situations will be **R.id.nav_host_fragment** (NavHostFragment container (View) id defined on xml layout).